# HTML/JS -- get clicked row

Tags: javascript

I have a table where each row has a hyperlink. When the link is clicked, a URL to aggregate data will be called. I need to pass the clicked row/record to this URL but unsure of how to get the clicked row.

Here's some sample code

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="aggregate()">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="aggregate()">Eve</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function aggregate(){
       //get clicked row, pass as parameter 
    };
</script>
```

Do I instead need to wrap each row in a form and do a form submit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` to the function to get the row by using `t.parentNode.parentNode` and perform some action on it

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="aggregate(this)">Jill</td>
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="aggregate(this)">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="aggregate(this)">Eve</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function aggregate(t){
       //get clicked row, pass as parameter 
      t.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Think this should do it. Grabs the element that was clicked, and iterates through each parent until the tagname matches and returns that match as the row var.

```
function aggregate(ev){
    var el = ev.currentTarget,
        row = (function() {
            while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.tagName === 'tr');
            return el;
        })();

    // Do stuff with "row" ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function pass the event and check the target of the event.

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function check_me(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello World!")
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a  onclick="check_me(event);">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put id to all table data and the access the `<td>` using your javascript program.

```
<td id='record-1'><a htef="...?row=record-1">link</a><td>


<script>

function tty() {

  document.getElementById('record-1').
  // do what ever you want to do this your row
}
```